# how to connect a swagger if there are no controllers in the project

Tags: api, kotlin, gradle, swagger

how to connect a swagger or automatically create api methods documentation if there are no controllers in the project, RouterFunctionDsl is used

org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server
kotlin gradle

The project on kotlin gradle
org.springframework.web.reactive